# How would I keep this script from executing multiple times and waiting until the script is answered?

Tags: javascript, html

This runs an if statement that generates a math addition problem, I have a input asking the user how many questions they would like to complete but when it runs it generates all at the same time instead of waiting for the user to answer the first question then clearing the innerHTML. Is there a way to stop it from generating them all at once and waiting until the question is answered correctly using if statements?

```
           if(equation == "Addition(+)"){
                number = document.getElementById('problems').value;

                for(var i = 0; i<number; i++){       
               var inputedanswer = 
               document.getElementById('answerfield').value;
                  //Creates addition problem
                a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
                b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);

                if(inputedanswer == null){
                   //Trying to make it run only once
                var answer = (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
                //Creates question using the Math Random above
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                var text = document.createTextNode(a + " + " + b + " = ")
                p.appendChild(text);
                document.getElementById('question').appendChild(p);
                //Creates radio buttons for answers
                var select = document.createElement('input');
                var submit = document.createElement('button');
                document.getElementById('answerfield').appendChild(select);
                 document.getElementById('submit').appendChild(submit);
                submit.innerHTML = "Check Answer";
                //Submitting answer and checks if it is correct
            submit.onclick = function(){
                if(select.value != answer){
                    alert("I am sorry but that is not the correct answer, Please try again!");
                } 
                else{
                    alert("That's correct!");
                    document.getElementById('field').innerHTML = "";
                    //Ask Erickson
                }
            }
        }
                }
            }
```

Comment: it would be best to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Right now its hard to help without the full context of your problem. Try creating a working code snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So you want when the users respond the first question appear the second question then if the user respond the second question appear the third... etc?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this all in one method. You should split it into different methods (see list down below) that are connected to specific event listeners.
It seems to me as the user should get a list of questions to answer? When he answers one, it should be marked as either correct or wrong.

What about this procedure:
**1)** Ask the user how many questions he wants to answer
  --> click on "Start test"
**2)** Prepare a number of question according to the user's input, save them in an array (one item = Task + Answers + Solution)
**3)** Parse all questions into HTML
  --> check when an answer was given, whether it was right, show result

Of course you can change this procedure to your needs. You could also ask for the number of requested questions, save it as variable and then always generate a question, show it as HTML, wait for an answer (button click), check answer, show solution, move on to next question until enough questions were shown.

Whatever you do, use multiple methods and call them only if the user does something (clicks on a button or gives an answer, for example)

Answer (score -1):

Put it into a function and then once he answers the question call the function.

```
if(he answers the question) {
    waitForQuestion();
}





function waitForQuestion(){
          if(equation == "Addition(+)"){
                number = document.getElementById('problems').value;

                for(var i = 0; i<number; i++){       
               var inputedanswer = 
               document.getElementById('answerfield').value;
                  //Creates addition problem
                a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
                b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);

                if(inputedanswer == null){
                   //Trying to make it run only once
                var answer = (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
                //Creates question using the Math Random above
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                var text = document.createTextNode(a + " + " + b + " = ")
                p.appendChild(text);
                document.getElementById('question').appendChild(p);
                //Creates radio buttons for answers
                var select = document.createElement('input');
                var submit = document.createElement('button');
                document.getElementById('answerfield').appendChild(select);
                 document.getElementById('submit').appendChild(submit);
                submit.innerHTML = "Check Answer";
                //Submitting answer and checks if it is correct
            submit.onclick = function(){
                if(select.value != answer){
                    alert("I am sorry but that is not the correct answer, Please try again!");
                } 
                else{
                    alert("That's correct!");
                    document.getElementById('field').innerHTML = "";
                    //Ask Erickson
                }
            }
        }
                }
            }
}
```